# horizontal legend is going out of svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend

I have a multiline chart with legends in D3js.
Two problem I am facing

1. legend text are differ in length so If I give fixed x for the legend rect and text sometimes it overlaps the other legend.
2. when say 20 legends come horizontally it does not goes to next line.it goes overflow svg.I want it to automatically comes to next line.

   ```
   var color = that.getColor(series);
       legend = svg.selectAll(".legend").data(series.slice().reverse()).enter().append("g").attr("class", "legend").attr('transform', 'translate(-20,'+(height+50)+')');
       legend.append("rect").attr("x", function(d,i){return (i*105);}).attr("y", "0").attr("width", 12).attr("height", 12).style("fill", color);
       legend.append("text").attr("x", function (d, i) {return (i*105+15);}).attr("y", "11").text(function (d) {return d;});
   ```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7mkg/1/)

Comment: can you please put a fiddle.

Comment: added.please provide a way to set x based on previous string length.as if you give big string it overlaps

Answer (score 0):

The main logic is about calculating the translate for the legend group.
I worked on the length of the label and added a y translate if the width is exceeded. something like this:

```
   .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        var y = line *50;
        var x = col;
        col += d.name.length*13+ 10;
        if (col > width){
            //width is exceeded add new line
            x = 0;
            col =d.name.length*13+ 10;
            line++;
            y = line *50;
        }
```

Full code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/jojjz2pf/8/